# How to restore Nuget package

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I have added solution into TFS.

Now other users have taken latest that solution project.

Problem: all users are facing an issue for Ninject and other references are not found which are added through Package manager.

Please guide me.

I tried to apply - "Nuget Restore" command in package console but, it says, command not exists.

Please help how to resolve.

Comment: If suggested answer helped you fix the problem please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always run the the following in Nuget package manager console:

**Update-Package -reinstall -ProjectName testProject**

When something like what you mentioned happens. Make sure instead of testProject you put your testProject